# How to add items dynamically to a list box in GWT

Tags: gwt

I need to add items dynamically on click of listbox in Gwt . Which handler do I need to use?
Later I will be able to use addChangeHandler once items are added to listbox. 
If i use click handler to add items to listbox, items are added to listbox. But on click of listbox, listbox items are not listed. Listbox closes immediately on click of it.
How to resolve this issue

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple code to demonstrate how to add items to the `ListBox`.

You need to understand some things first:

- `ClickEvent` is fired **whenever** you click on the `ListBox`: first when you click to show the list and second when you click to select an item;
- `ChangeEvent` is fired when you change the selected item - you can not use it to track the change of item list itself;

---

```
public class ListBoxTest implements EntryPoint {

    private TextArea log = new TextArea();
    private ListBox listBox = new ListBox();
    private int i;

    @Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            listBox.addItem("item " + i++);

        listBox.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                log(event.toDebugString());
                for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                    listBox.addItem("item " + i++);
            }
        });

        listBox.addChangeHandler(new ChangeHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onChange(ChangeEvent event) {
                log(event.toDebugString());
            }
        });

        RootPanel.get().add(listBox);
        RootPanel.get().add(log);
    }

    private void log(String text) {
        String logText = log.getText();
        if(!logText.isEmpty())
            logText+= "\n";

        logText+= text;

        log.setText(logText);
    }
}
```